# Declare multiple variables in one class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have an assignment to build a simple multi-widget application in Android Studio and I am trying to figure out how to declare multiple variables inside one class for a multi-page photo rating app. I have 4 pages, and 4 photos with a `RatingBar` underneath each of them. I would like to have the average of all the ratings displayed on the top of the page. For simplicity I have it being cast to the page title using `SetTitle`

How can I write this java in such a way that I can access all 4 of my ratings and apply the basic math to them? This is technically beyond what we have been taught so far in this class.

```
package ca.bcit.comp2052.a00587366.multiplewidgetsapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Start of rating bar

        RatingBar ratingBar1 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
        ratingBar1.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar1, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                // Implement your logic here               

                float total = 0;
                total += ratingBar1.getRating();
//                total += ratingBar2.getRating();
//                total += ratingBar3.getRating();
//                total += ratingBar4.getRating();
                float average = total / 4;
                setTitle("Average: " + average);

            }
        });
        // end of rating bar
        Button buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new 
        android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
        Main2Activity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably have them as `R.id.ratingBars[0]` and so forth, but since you don't, assuming it's `R.id.ratingBar1` through `R.id.ratingBar4`, you can do something like this:

```java
final RatingBar[] ratingBars = {
    (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1),
    (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar2),
    (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar3),
    (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar4)
};

for (final RatingBar ratingBar : ratingBars) {
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar bar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            // Implement your logic here               

            float total = 0.0f;
            for (final RatingBar ratingBar : ratingBars) {
                total += ratingBar.getRating();
            }
            float average = total / 4.0f;
            setTitle("Average: " + average);
        }
    });
}
```

This also makes it easier to add new `RatingBar`s if necessary. You just add them to the original array initialization list at the top and everything is taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling them by

```
Main2Activity.ratingBar2.getRating()
```

But they should be public, which is not too good.

Elsewhere you can declare them private and the create public getter methods to retrieve them from external classes.